# Is this a valid proof of the chain rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, chain-rule

Is this a valid proof of the chain rule?

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{a \to x} \frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{x - a} &=
\lim_{a \to x} \frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{x - a} * \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}\\
&=\lim_{a \to x} \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a} * \frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\\
&=\lim_{a \to x} \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a} * \lim_{a \to x}\frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\\
&=g'(x)*\lim_{a \to x}\frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}
\end{align*}$$
As $a \to x$, $g(a) \to g(x)$. Thus,
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{a \to x}\frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} &= \lim_{g(a) \to g(x)}\frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} = f'(g(x))\\
\lim_{a \to x} \frac{f(g(x)) -f(g(a))}{x - a}&= g'(x)*f'(g(x))
\end{align*}$$

Comment: There is a problem with the proof, which is that you do not know that $g(x)\neq g(a)$ for all $x$ near $a$. So you cannot in general rewrite the fraction $\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a}$ as $\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$ and break up the limits. The proof is "morally" right, but doesn't quite work in general and more care is needed.

Comment: Lucian, as Arturo pointed out there is a problem with your proof. Here is the [correct proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof).

Comment: I think a nicer (equivalent) characterisation of the derivative is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|h(x)-h(a)-h'(a)(x-a)| \le \epsilon |x-a|$. This avoids the special case of dealing with $g(x) = 0$.